# How to add comments in GDNS files?

Tags: godot

I've attempted to add some comments in `.gdns` files, but neither `#`, `//`, `/**/` or `--` worked.

I've resorted to adding my notes to README.md, but I'd like to know if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gdns` files are not actual scripts, but are only resource definitions that contain references to a GDNativeLibrary and a particular class. The fact that they appear as editable in the Godot script editor is a bug.